# CSS - Image gets hidden in the overflowed area

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I have created a segment from a circle but when I try to apply a background image to it, it applies it to the whole circle resulting in the image getting centered somewhere below what the user can't see.

[image]

Right now, only the portion of the circle that overlaps with the rectangle gets displayed thanks to `overflow: hidden`, I have just disabled the `hidden` for now to show how the image is actually getting rendered.

Can someone please tell me how I can apply a background image *only* to the portion of the circle that's visible?

This is the result I want:
[image]

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/segment-background-image-msu63

^ I achieved this by hardcoding the position of the image but I am looking for a CSS oriented approach because that'll be much more dynamic.

EDIT: so I was able to figure it out. The trick was to place another div on top of the semi-circle and add the image on that and set the `overflow` to `hidden` on the parent div. It works like a charm!

p.s the demo is updated with the solution.

Comment: Which portion of the circle should be visible? And can you explain a little further what you want to happen?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Are you able to make the heart into another div and use z-index to layer it instead of going this approach? it would be much easier to toss that heart around doing it this way.

Comment: That seems like a good approach. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick was to place another div on top of the semi-circle and add the image on that and set the overflow to hidden on the parent div. It works like a charm!

p.s the demo is updated with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the `background-position` top `top center`:

```
background: url("./360.v1.png") top center no-repeat rgba(85, 112, 24, 0.76);
```

Comment: This approach will only work for the image provided. I'm looking for a more dynamic approach.